Regarding APC and withdrawal of accepted paper
I recently submitted my paper to a well-known journal, who accepted it after review. The 'Fees and Charges' of their site mentions that Article Processing Charge will be taken 'only' for Open Access. However, they mentioned it somewhere else that they only publish Open Access. My paper has not entered the copy-editing stage yet, which will commence only after payment. At this stage, can I withdraw my submission? They have also not mentioned about withdrawing charges.

After sending the acceptance of my paper, the editor has asked for a Finalized version of my manuscript, which I have not submitted yet. Also, I have been asked to pay fees within 5 days to allow further proceeding in the endeavor. Is there anything to be done at this juncture?

Just to be clear, you want to withdraw because you can't afford the APC, and didn't realize there wasn't any option to publish non-OA, and not pay the APC.

Yes, you can withdraw your paper any time up until you give up copyright or assign them a license. And, for open access publication giving up copyright might not happen (probably doesn't happen). The paper is yours subject to any license you have agreed to.
I would find a withdrawal charge unusual for a reputable journal, actually, but can't guarantee it won't be tried.
It would be an ethical violation for them to publish something without holding copyright or a license to do so. But if they do have a license from you, then you can't withdraw it.
For some users, some journals will waive APC. You can also ask. Pleading poverty and lack of funding sources works for some.
